# Spring not calling @Bean method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm putting multiple `@Bean` methods in a `@SpringBootApplication` class to create required beans. All of them run except for one. That one Bean method is never run and thus, the corresponding class (which is annotated as a Service) complains with an exception: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

Any reason why one Bean method will not run while the others in that same class do?

The method in Application.java, haProxyService is never called while consulService does get called.

```
// Application.java:
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    //Config for services
    //Consul
    String consulPath = "/usr/local/bin/com.thomas.Oo.consul.consul";
    String consulConfPath = "/root/Documents/consulProto/web.json";

    //HAProxy
    String haproxyPath = "/usr/local/bin/haproxy";
    String haproxyConfFilePath = "/root/Documents/consulProto/haproxy.conf";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsulService consulService(){
        return new ConsulService(consulPath, consulConfPath);
    }

    @Bean
    public HAProxyService haProxyService(){
        return new HAProxyService(haproxyPath, haproxyConfFilePath);
    }
}


// ConsulService.java
@Service
public class ConsulService extends BaseService {
    String executablePath;
    String confFilePath;

    public ConsulService(String consulPath, String confFilePath) {
        this.executablePath = consulPath;
        this.confFilePath = confFilePath;
    }
}


// HAProxyService.java
@Service
public class HAProxyService extends BaseService {
    String executablePath;
    String confFilePath;

    public HAProxyService(String executablePath, String confFilePath) {
        this.executablePath = executablePath;
        this.confFilePath = confFilePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I remove the @Service from the offending class, the Bean method magically gets invoked now....... What is going on

Comment: You are going to have to show some code. Nobody can guess this for sure.

Comment: Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/thomas-oo/7d129f4a042fd87a8ed33f87a8dad396

The method in Application.java, haProxyService is never called while consulService does get called. When I remove @Service from HAProxyService, the bean method now gets called.. but my problem remains unsolved

Comment: You are mixing manual bean creation with @Bean and class annotations (@Service) for the component scan. This leads to duplicated instances that may result in the exception above (because multiple candidates are found).

Comment: @meistermeier, Thank you, sorry I'm a bit new to spring... but I understand what you mean. However, how would I inject the strings into my classes if I were to tag them as `@Services` and not do any manual bean creation? Do I define the strings as beans? And if so how?

Comment: currently the docs for the spring pages are down but you should inject config params by using `@Value` and `@PropertySource` (web search keyword hints ;) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the [`@Service`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) annotations.

You are mixing manual bean creation with [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) and class annotations (`@Service`, `@Controller`, `@Component`, etc.) for the component scan. This leads to duplicated instances.

Otherwise, if you want to leave `@Service`s and not to do manual bean creation, you should remove the methods with `@Bean` annotation and inject string values using [`@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation.

Example:

```
// Application.java:
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

// HAProxyService.java
@Service
public class HAProxyService extends BaseService {

    @Value("/usr/local/bin/haproxy")
    private String executablePath;
    @Value("/root/Documents/consulProto/haproxy.conf")
    private String confFilePath;

}

// ConsulService.java
@Service
public class ConsulService extends BaseService {

    @Value("/usr/local/bin/com.thomas.Oo.consul.consul")
    private String executablePath;
    @Value("/root/Documents/consulProto/web.json")
    private String confFilePath;

}
```

After doing this I would recommend you to read about [externalizing your configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), so you can define these strings in `application.properties` file and benefit from changing them easily without recompiling your application.